# how to assign each list item to the same button in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

this is my
[homePage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5P0l.png)

as you can see I have some items and a button that I use to add them to the chartScreen, which is [chartScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOHxk.png) , I'm using context api to store items in cartContext.js  where each item has its own key to make things easier but I cannot correlate the logic for how to assign each item to the button so whenever I press the button its own item gets added to the chartScreen.

```
const CartContext = createContext();

export function CartProvider({ children }){
    const [items, setItems] = useState(
        [
          {
            title: "Pınar",
            text: "Pınar Klasik Dana Sucuk (225g)",
            pic: <Image
              style={styles.image1}
              source={require("./Images/klasik_dana_sucuk_paket.png")} />,
            key: 1,
          },
          {
            text: "Pınar Uzun Sosis (225g)",
            pic: <Image
              style={styles.image1}
              source={require("./Images/pinar_uzun_sosis.png")} />,
            key: 2,
          },
        ]
  const [store, setStore] = useState([]);

  const addToCart = (text) => {
    setStore((prevState) => [
        ...prevState, 
        text,
    ]);
  }

return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{items,setItems, addToCart, store}}>
        {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
)
```

I found a cheeky way to send a specific item from addButton.js

```
const AddButton = () => {
 const { items } = useContext(CartContext);
  const { addToCart } = useContext(CartContext);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => addToCart(items[0])}>
        <Text>+</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

and in the chartScreen I view it just like this

```
 const ChartScreen = () => {
  const { store } = useContext(CartContext);

  if(store.length != 0) {
        return (
          <FlatList 
          data={store}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.listItem}>
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.pic} {item.text}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
        )
      }
```

this is for sure not even the wrong way to achieve the goal so can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import your button and make it common for all the items, and pass the value to it.
Here is your button code

```
const AddButton = ({item}) => {
 const { items } = useContext(CartContext);
  const { addToCart } = useContext(CartContext);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => 
           addToCart(item?.text)}>
        <Text>+</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

Here you can make button for all you item

```
  const ChartScreen = () => {
  const { store } = useContext(CartContext);

  if(store.length != 0) {
        return (
          <FlatList 
          data={store}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.listItem}>
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.pic} {item.text}</Text>
            <AddButton item={item} />
            </View>
          )}
        />
        )
      }
```